# Publishing schema as wcf service trouble

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl, biztalk

I'm trying to publish some HL7 schemas (with quite a few ) as wcf services using the "WCF Service Publishing Wizard". The wizard seemingly runs and completes just fine, creating a service that exposes the schemas I want. But when I try to browse the newly created service,  I get "Server Application Unavailable"... I looked in the eventviewer and noticed the error message: "System.OutOfMemoryException". I tested once more while having a look in "Task Manager", and i noticed that the aspnet_wp.exe was consuming more than 1 GB of RAM before it was terminated (application pool probably recycled after reaching maximum memory consumption allowed).

I was quite puzzled as to why this happened, so I decided to publish the same schema as a ASMX webservice using the "Web Services Publishing Wizard", to see if it would make any difference. After running the wizard I tried to browse the service, and it worked out just fine with no problmes whatsoever. I looked at the generated WSDL definition, which was huge, and all the referenced schemas was added as inline schemas, and not as include or import.

This left me to believe that it could be an issue with the generation of the WSDL, having so many includes in the published schema, but im not at all sure yet as to if this could be the case...

Is there anyone who have experienced similar problems trying to publish schemas as wcf services?
I welcome all suggestions that could lead me in the right direction in this issue.

Thanks.

-M.Papas

Answer (score 0):

This problem is definitely a memory issue with the WSDL generation tool.  Publishing complex or even semi-complex schemas as Web Services or WCF Services usually ends in out of memory exceptions.  I've ran into this a few times doing a SAP iDoc demo and its just that the schema is too complex for the WSDL tool.  Hope that helps.